# Can I use ES6 modules in Node.js 8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Can I use ES6 module syntax with Node.js starting from version 8? 
Similar questions have already been asked on this site, but answers there are obsolete. I wonder if the situation has changed with new version of Node.js?

Comment: Still a work in progress I think, but [this might be worth keeping an eye on](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) - "This small (< 40 kB), zero dependency, package is all you need to enable ECMAScript modules in Node 4+ today!". From the fella that brought you lodash.

Comment: **Yes!** u can..using Babel.

Comment: It's possible as of today, see simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node/50641589#50641589

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c

It is in progress but the ETA is 2018 at the earliest.