# ES6 import statements not working in Node v8.4.0

Tags: node.js

I'm using the latest version of Node.js that is v8.4.0. However, in the import and export statements, I'm getting errors:

```
import express from 'express';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

What Node.js version should I install in order to work these ES6 codes?

- OS - Ubuntu 17.04
- node -v: v8.4.0
- npm -v: 5.3.0

Comment: what is that opening brace? Import should be in the top-most level of your file

Comment: no, it was just in the error logs

Comment: ES6 does not support `import` on Node.JS. Use `const express = require('express');`

Comment: so which version does support import? if its es7, which node js version should I install to make it work?

Comment: @GijoVarghese No version supports it yet. You'll need to use babel.

Comment: I was just wondering because of most of the tutorials now I see uses import instead of require. So how do they do it?

Comment: You can try [@std/esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@std/esm).

Comment: It's possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node/50641589#50641589

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way that I have worked around this issue...

Install babel stuff for the project:

```
$ npm install babel-register babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Create an index.js file that is the main entry point into the app:

```
// index.js 
// by requiring `babel/register`, all of our successive `require`s will be Babel'd
require('babel-register')({
   presets: [ 'es2015' ]
});

require('./server');
```

Then, create a file called server.js that will have your normal index code:

```
// server.js
import express from 'express';

var app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

And run:

```
$ node index.js
```

Comment: From https://babeljs.io/env/: "instead of continuing yearly presets, the team recommends using babel-preset-env". Therefore the 'es2015' preset in your code should probably be updated to 'env' (babel-preset-env)

Comment: import with directory name showing error. unexpected token for  __

import pdf from __dirname + '/../../../index.js';

Answer (score -1):

const express = require('express');
is the right syntax as some es6 features ie import express from express is currently not available with node!