# Use ES6 'import' instead of 'require' in microservices framework for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, microservices, moleculer

I am using moleculer microservices framework for Node.js. Now, I need to use ES6 `import` instead of `require`.

For Example,

```
const { abc } = require("../../index.js"); **// This is working well.** <br>
import { abc } from "../../index.js";      **// This isn't working and throw the error.**
```

I am getting error like **`Unexpected token import`**.
I've installed Babel(JavaScript compiler) as well.

Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 import statements not working in Node v8.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176973/es6-import-statements-not-working-in-node-v8-4-0)

Comment: make sure you changed `modules.exports` to `export` in index.js

Comment: You have babel installed. How are you *using* babel?

Comment: I've just installed babel's require packages (e.g npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript). I don't know how to use babel. Can you please guide me if I am wrong somewhere ? Do I need to add any configurations for Babel ?

Comment: Yes, you actually need to apply Babel to your code and generate the transpiled code, before running *that*. Please read the documentation of Babel.