# How to Import Plottable.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import, plottable

I am fairly new to javaScript. I am having issues finding out how to import and use the Plottalbe.js (along with D3 that is part of it) libraries. Can anyone show me a working example of an HTML and .js file that uses Plottable? I must have severe blindness because I cannot find anything on this.

I used npm and the package was placed into C:\Users\me\node_modules.

Here is what I have tried so far. Excuse my code. I have tried different approaches, and I still fail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <!-- <link     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/1.15.0/plottable.css"
    rel="stylesheet" /> -->
  <script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
  <!-- <script     src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/plottable@3/plottable.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>JS</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the app.js.

```
//import { Plottable } from "plottable";
// var Plottable = require('plottable');

require(['plottable'], function (plottable) {
// var Plottable = require('plottable');
});

// define(function (require){
// var Plottable = require('plottable');
// });
```

Comment: `import` or `require` should be all you need.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I have multiple different combinations of import and require, and since I barely know what I am doing I must keep screwing it up somehow.

Comment: Add the code you're trying to your question.  It's pretty tough to help you without seeing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `import Plottable from 'plottable';` to the top of your js file (assuming you are using Node).  If not, you will need to `require` your dependency using the *full path* to the file.

Comment: I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' and it points to the line with the import. All the rest in app.js is commented out. So it's just the import.

Comment: Are you using Node?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: No I am not. I am using strictly javaScript/HTML. I used npm to install the stuff, maybe that put it in a place I can't access?

Comment: Updated answer.  You were confused by examples that all use Node.

Comment: I cannot get it to work unfortunately. I get 'not allowed to load local resource' and 'script error for http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror'. Looks like the js uses require too so I must be confusing it somehow. Thanks for the help but I guess I'm stuck on this.