# Jest/Mocha + TypeScript: Jest/Mocha tries to read JS dependencies and fails - "unexpected token import"

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, jestjs

So, I'm testing a TypeScript file with Mocha, I access a dependency in the file via `import`, and the function to test is in the same file, like below:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo-library';

// I'm trying to test this
export const myHelperFunction = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
  // Foo not used
};

export class BigClass {
  public doStuff() {
    // uses Foo
  }
}
```

Then I have my test file:

```
import { myHelperFunction } from './my-file';

it('does the right thing', () => {
    expect(myHelperFunction(2, 3)).to.equal(5);
});
```

Now, Mocha tries to parse `foo-library` contents while attempting to execute tests, and throws an error that says "unexpected token import", even though the import is not used in `myHelperFunction`. The file is in ES6 format and Mocha/Node is unable to parse it correctly.

Should the dependency files be transpiled to ES5 somehow? Is it possible to skip the imports altogether while testing? I have tried to mock the imports with several libraries (Sinon etc.) and that hasn't worked either.

I'd greatly appreciate any ideas.

Comment: It's likely that the error is in your test file, not in `Foo` or `myHelperFunction`. Node simply cannot use import. You need to either transpile everything to ES5, or use [babel loader](http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/), or [enable experimental import support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node).

Comment: @zeh How would I do that? My test command now looks like this:
`"test": "mocha --require babel-register src/**/test.ts"`
...but I still get the same error, i.e.:
`/home/maija/ionic/mobiilikasvio2/node_modules/@ionic-native/sqlite/index.js:20
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question, try `mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/test.ts`.  Mocha won't run TS files right off the bat. You have to use `ts-node/register` to run them as TS files.

Comment: You might have to install [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) if you haven't already, that was the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I switched to Jest.

Actually I had some problems with it as well. The issue was that JavaScript files in node_modules weren't transpiled. The working configuration is below.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.4.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.2",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.2",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest" // had to add this
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(@ionic-native)/)" // had to add this
  ]
}
```