# why node uses require not import?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

I'm learning node.js and am wondering why it uses the `require` syntax rather than the `import` syntax which React uses.

i.e.

`const Validator = require("validator");`

VS

`import Validator from "validator";`

I believed `import` is es6 but I don't think that explains why it's not used in node.

Comment: "*I don't think that explains why it's not used in node*" - of course it does: Node.js if far older than ES6

Comment: Have a look at the history of [commonjs modules](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules) - the discussion was around 2010, five years before ES6

Comment: because I often see arrow functions and other es6 features used in node I thought import would have been the same, it's available in chrome & V8 too.  But I see why it's  not supported from the [link](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) @axm__ shared in his answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `import` and `default` are newer ES6 features, not yet used by node. [Node is actually already implementing the new features as experiment though](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html): with the `--experimental-modules` flag and only for files saved with `.mjs` extension.

Transpilers like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) make it possible to write modern, spec approved and /or experimental [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript). In an ecosystem of bundlers like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with transpilers like babel, it becomes easy to write maintainable, future-proof javascript, while the code remains widely suported because it's transformed to `commonjs` (the format you see recognizable by`require` (the old-school `import`) and `module.exports` (the old-school `export`).

Comment: Note that Bable and Typescript's implementation of the `import` system is not spec approved. Specifically the spec requires that the imported module's file name match the string you pass to the `import` statement. The whole thing with the `.mjs` type is due to the impossibility of making the ES6 module system work with Commonjs (node's module system)

Answer (score 1):

Probably for historical reasons. node.js and chrome (v8 engine) are older than ES6 standard.

On the other hand, see:
[How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

You may use import, too.

Answer (score 1):

> I believed import is es6 but I don't think that explains why it's not
>   used in node.

Just like the way NodeJS implements their entire library which tons of asynchronous functions which only support callback-based approach. Thinking this way and you'll realize that, sooner or later, the NodeJS framework will definitely support the `import` syntax and upgrade all of those asynchronous functions to support promise-based.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, *require* is used to load modules, while *import* is used in ECMAScript modules (ESM modules) for loading other modules, either statically or dynamically.

The major difference between *require* and *import* is that *require* will automatically scan **node_modules** to find modules, but *import*, **which comes from ES6, won’t**.

Most people use *Babel* to compile *import* and *export*, which makes import act the same as *require*.

1. require is more of dynamic analysis, and import is more of static analysis.
2. require throws error at runtime, and import throws error while parsing.
3. require is nonlexical and import is lexical.