# Why not using import in Nodejs but arrow functions

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm new to nodejs. 
I see we are using

```
const http = require('http')
```

instead of import . I found of that is because nodejs is older than es6

[why node uses require not import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567493/why-node-uses-require-not-import)

However, I can use arrow functions. which is es6. how it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567493/why-node-uses-require-not-import

Comment: yes, I saw that. my question is how come arrow function which is from es6 possible while import is NOT possible

Answer (score 3):

It's finally happened: nearly 4 years after the import keyword was introduced in ES6, Node.js introduced experimental support for ES6 imports and exports. In Node.js 12, you can use import and export in your project if you do both of the below items.

1) Add the `--experimental-modules` flag when running Node.js

2) Use the `.mjs` extension or set `"type": "module"` in your package.json.

This package.json is very important. The type: "module" property tells Node.js to treat .js files as ESM modules. In other words, `{"type":"module"}` tells Node.js to expect import and export statements in .js files.

You can run file like this
`node --experimental-modules index.js`