# Unable to write ES6 syntax in Node Typescript app

Tags: node.js, express, import, mean-stack

I am getting an `exception` while importing module

[image]

Here is code

```
import * as express from 'express';

export class Server {

    app: express.Application
    constructor() {
        const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT
        this.app = express()
        this.app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on Port: ${port}`)
        })
    }
}

export default new Server()
```

**Note:**
I am creating `API` with `Angular 7`, both client & server apps have common `node_modules` and other configuration files like `package.json and angular.json`

The same code, I am running with `Angular 6` is working fine. Is there any configuration issue?

**Update 1:**

Old `Angular 6` project, I created with `Node v8.9.3`
and new `Angular 7` project with `Node v10.14.2` and facing issue that server code is running with old project but giving stated error with new project.

**Update 2:**

When I changed it to

```
var express = require("express");

const app = express()
const port = 3001 || process.env.PORT
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on Port: ${port}`)
})

module.exports = app;
```

It worked fine... but I need to use ES6 syntax

Comment: Is this the whole code of the Server ?

Comment: Yes, it is the complete code

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with this part of the code. Are you sure this part is causing the compilation to fail ?

Comment: this code is working fine with `Angular 6` but not with `Angular 7`. Is there any compatibility or syntax issue

Comment: This code has nothing to do with Angular, thats Node. Did you change your node version ?

Comment: Yes, it is now `Node v10.14.2` and `npm v6.4.1`

Comment: Please provide that information as well as the previous version in your question. Also Maybe the Snippet where you import/use the Server (as you seem to import it at some point)

Comment: Both apis have same code just copied and pasted from old project. What I need to provide to the answer i.e. `package.json`, `angular.json` or else.

Comment: Just state what version of node you had before and after. Maybe this helps. And the part of the code where ou import the Server.

Comment: just running this file with `nodemon --exec ts-node ./api/server.ts`, nowhere server is being imported. Update question, please review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be problem in **tsconfig.json**. Check **compilerOptions.module**. Example:

```
   {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a pertaining to Angular. It's an express js application used along with Angular.

Comment: @Vinit Sarvade I dont write about Angular here). I use typescript in server side and sometimes problem is in a bad config. Please explain me in more detail your comment...

Comment: This isn't a problem of bad config. You need to also install typings for your express application. Please install the following `npm i -D @types/express` and then modify the import as `import express from 'express'`

Comment: Also make sure you are running the application using `tsc` command. Assuming that your server code is in server.ts, run it using `tsc server.ts`

Comment: @Vinit Sarvade If **target** will be not **es5** you will get this error. Because in output will be **import** and nodejs don't understant it without flag --experimental-modules yet.

Comment: If you running your server with `tsc` you don't need to specify the target as it will directly run typescript.

Comment: @Vinit Sarvade :) Yes i use tsc but with my specific config

Comment: @MrM Thank you for your answer, I changed my code to `"module": "esnext"` but still error is there. If you believe you can solve this please test this source code [https://github.com/wasifnaeem/Test](https://github.com/wasifnaeem/Test) and let me know where is the problem?

Comment: @WasiF Try to use commonjs instead esnext. I cloned your repo, change esnext to commonjs and run `npm run server`, and it work correct. )

Comment: @MrM Many thanks my friend, you saved my time. Changing to `commonjs` worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out:

Node does not allow ECMAScriptModules yet (experimental)

So instead of this:

```
import * as express from "express";
```

you should use this:

```
var express = require("express");
```

But you can use the flag [--experimental-modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules) to make it compile (its not stable yet).

See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: same command is being used to run both the applications. It's a standard command used by professional

Comment: then why this ES6 syntax is supporting the previous project while it have previous packages installed than new project have latest packages installed

Comment: Maybe it got compiled with babel ? (that was a possibility) or also this command

Comment: How to check with what it is being compiled?

Comment: the commands with whom you started the server determine the way it got compiled.(babel /src or node /src)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185478/discussion-between-joniras-and-wasif).