# Seeing console error while initializing server - import not define?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm using `import { isValid, format, parse, subHours, differenceInHours } from 'date-fns';` in one of the `.js` file.

In test, I imported the file correctly and tests passed, but when starting server I see issue -

```
[error] - Error initializing server ../utils.js
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { isValid, format, parse, subHours, differenceInHours } from 'date-fns';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
```

Do you see any mistake in way I should import?

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Answer (score 0):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` is usually because the version of javascript/node that is running the code isn't new enough; it doesn't know about the keyword `import`.

Instead of `import { isValid, format, parse, subHours, differenceInHours } from 'date-fns';` try using the `require()` method...

This should work for node 6.4.0 and above:

```
const { isValid, format, parse, subHours, differenceInHours } = require('date-fns');
```

or something like this for node 4

```
var dateFns = require('date-fns');

var isValidDate = dateFns.isValid;
var formatDate = dateFns.format;
```

Answer (score 0):

You imported it right. a possible problem could be you are trying to use it without installing the package(date-fns) on your project. just check it's existance in your project's package.json. if you couldn't find it, install using npm

```
npm i date-fns
```