# How to fix Unexpected token { on controller.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jwt

I have some doubts on my code. The code below is my code.

```
import  {JwtHelperService}  from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
angular.module("appFoco", []).controller("LoginFormPDF", ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function($scope, $location, $http) {
const helper = new JwtHelperService();
console.log($scope);}])
```

And I want to fix this error => Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I am developing with angular and jwt and Nodejs.
How I can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Answer (score 0):

> import  {JwtHelperService}  from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

This is the culprit here , By your code i can see you are using angularJS,
For injecting a service in angularJS , you just have to do dependency injection in your controller.

You can't and dont't have to import it like this .

Just made a dependency injection like:

```
angular.module("appFoco", []).controller("LoginFormPDF", ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'JwtHelperService', function($scope, $location, $http, JwtHelperService) {
```

And dont forget to add this service in index.html script section.

If you still wish to use import statement, you have to introduce a ES6 to ES5 compiler to compile your code before running it.