# How to conditionally use either a built-in Node.js or a browser API method with ES6-style imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Example context**

I'm writing a library based on getting crypto-secure random bytes from a native source. I want to make the lib usable both in Node.js and in the browser. This requires using different built-in APIs in the two environments.

**The problem**

I'm searching for the general solution to use

1. either Node.js API methods with ES6-style imports
2. OR browser API methods,

based on environment detection.

**The problem applied to the above example context**

To make the lib usable both in Node.js and in browser environments, `crypto.randomBytes()` is used in Node.js, and `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` is used in the browser as underlying the random source.

The currently working solution is based on Node's dynamic `require`. The lib detects the environment, then:

- in Node.js, it uses `require('crypto')`,
- in the browser, it uses `window.crypto.getRandomValues()`, which is simply available in the global scope and nothing has to be required/imported.

**The question**

Instead of using `require()`, I'm wondering if it's possible to use an ES6-style `import { randomFill } from 'crypto';` with environment detection. The import would still be run in the browser, but there is no such built-in module in the browser, so that would be a problem.

Do you have any experience how transpilers (like babel) and bundlers (like rollup) handle this kind of problem with static imports?

---

Note: this is **not** a duplicate of [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node). I know there are ESM and the `--experimental-modules`, and it works well. My question regards the case when both browser and Node.js environments are the target of an implementation, but due to the different environments, different platform-provided APIs must be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: i dont think its possible to do conditional es6 imports... but maybe there's a way now?

Comment: @alfasin Thank you for your response. This is not a duplicate of that question. I edited mine and explained why.

Comment: Just found https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec/blob/master/README.md

Comment: There are dynamic ESM imports, but they’re not synchronous. Use `require` or import a module with a uniform interface that itself gets replaced based on the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but the way I solve this is basically through my webpack build.

I might have an import a bit like:

```
import { base64encode } from './base64';
```

In this directory I have 2 files:

```
base64.js
base64.web.js
```

It's possible to configure webpack to prefer the second one over the first. Other browser build tools have a feature like this as well.

This works really well for me, but this is only really an option if you have a 'build step'.

Comment: This is the correct approach. Don't do environment detection and dynamic module import, but let the module loader/bundler resolve the `crypto` import appropriately.