# Why does "import vue" line show "Uncaught SyntaxError"?

Tags: vue.js

Why do I see this error in console in any new vue application I create: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** in `main.js:1`

It appears before I write any code. I didn't understand what is wrong in ***import statement***. This is the original code I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

by the way, I use node v6.8.1

Comment: Are you running this script with node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: @DecadeMoon -- I use this command `npm run dev`. So I think this is related to your question.

Comment: @SebastianDiLuzio -- not it is not related to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to run it they way it's explained in the article i provided as duplicate.
The problem is the same, node does not yet support ES6 by default. (Import, Export is ES6 syntax)

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it.**
I recreated my vue project using node v12.4.0