# Node --experimental-modules - Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting an error when trying to import a local file, though no problem when using npm packages.

## server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import next from 'next'

import apis from './src/server/api'
```

## api.js

```
export default {
  ello: 'bye',
  jamie: 'hey'
}
```

## Starting app

```
node --experimental-modules --inspect server.js
```

## Error

```
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(node:20153) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:59
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/goldendemon.hutber.com/src/server/api' imported from /var/www/goldendemon.hutber.com/server.js
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:59:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:70:33)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:143:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:43:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I'm answering my own question if anybody else has this problem.

It turns out in experimental mode you need to define the full path with extension. So I am trying to import `index.js` thinking it will know.

To fix it:

```
import express from 'express'
import next from 'next'
import api from './src/server/api/index.js'
```

Comment: Jeez that was challenging...adding on the `.js` extension was what was holding me up ughh.  Your answer was helpful in diagnosing this!

Comment: How do you make this work with typescript ? when I run `tsc`, my files are compiled with imports without the extension.

Comment: For TypeScript (using Node 12), see the answer by Mateus (#answer-57558982). Using this (`--es-module-specifier-resolution=node`) option when running the script with `node` will solve the problem, though you may face other minor issues (eg, `__dirname` not being defined).

Comment: I figured Node experimental mode is too troublesome to just run a simple test script for playing around with ESM style imports, so I've resign myself to just transpiling, using `esbuild`. I wrote this short bash script to accomplish this:


`#!/bin/bash

script=$1
out_path==/tmp/$script-out.js
npx esbuild --platform=node --bundle --outfile=$out_path $script
node $out_path`

Comment: Hey, not sure if it will resolve your issue, but give it a shot. Check this [Github comment](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/113#issuecomment-783628854) and this [Node Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_imports). Summing up, you can add `"#api": "./src/server/api/index.js"` to your `package.json["imports"]`, and the import can be resolved with `import api from '#api'`

Answer (score 54):

on Node v12 you have 2 options:

1. Use `type="module"` in `package.json`, experimental modules and specify extensions with specifier-resolution like this:

   ```bash
   node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node server.js
   ```
2. Don't use specifier-resolution, you'll have to specify the extension of your files every where.

**Update** (from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4126424/basti)), for Node v18:

```bash
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js
```

Comment: Please note that there's no clarity yet if `--es-module-specifier-resolution` is here to stay. It will also mean that the code isn't compatible with other ES module runtimes (e.g. the browser).

Comment: got converted to: `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` seen [here (careful, theres a typo in that post)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30520#issuecomment-588288220)

Answer (score 3):

It should also work if you name your module file with a `.mjs` extension. Also, other ways to enable ESM are mentioned [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).

> Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to node as the initial input, or when referenced by import statements within ES module code:
>
> - Files ending in .mjs.
> - Files ending in .js, or extensionless files, when the nearest parent package.json file contains a top-level field "type" with a value of "module".
> - Strings passed in as an argument to --eval or --print, or piped to node via STDIN, with the flag --input-type=module.

Answer (score 0):

Or do like I did and just use transpilation the minute your source code deals with ES style module imports or some other non-standard JavaScript code, (E.g. TypeScript) on Node. For reference see this quick bash script I wrote, saved as `.script/run-it.sh` inside of my Node project:

```
#!/bin/bash

script=$1
out_path==/tmp/$script-out.js
npx esbuild --platform=node --bundle --outfile=$out_path $script
node $out_path
```

I added it as a run script in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "sst test",
    "start": "sst start",
    "build": "sst build",
    "deploy": "sst deploy",
    "remove": "sst remove",
    "run-it": "./.script/run-it.sh"
  },
```

And my target script (`import-test.js`), what I want to emit/transpile as JavaScript code:

```
import { default as myImport } from './lib/index.js'
console.log(myImport)
```

And now I run it:

```
$ npm run run-it ./import-test.js 

> my-nop@0.1.0 run-it /Users/jmquij0106/git/a-rebalancing-act
> ./.script/run-it.sh "./import-test.js"

[Function: main]
```

Bottomline is spare yourself the pain and just emit CommonJS compliant code whenever dealing with ES Modules on Node.js, see [this comment/issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2719#issuecomment-111213184).