# `import app from "./app"` does not work, but it's supposed to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

#### Goal

I want to import app from `app.js` to `init.js`.

#### Problem

For me, explicitly writing the file extension works, but omitting it does not.

- `"./app.js"` works ✅
- `"./app"` doesn't work

But the tutorial I'm following has **`"./app"` working.
So why does it not work for me?**

The only thing I did differently is adding `"type": "module"` inside `package.json`
and name `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` due to the updated Babel Node usage.

#### Versions

```
node v13.60
"@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
"@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
"express": "^4.17.1"
```

#### Error message

```
Error: Cannot find module /Users/leochoo/dev/wetube/app imported from /Users/leochoo/dev/wetube/init.js
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:100:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:72:33)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:156:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

#### Files related

```js
// app.js
const app = express();
...
export default app; //share this to init
```

```js
// init.js
import app from "./app.js";
```

```js
// babel.config.json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

```js
// package.json
{
  "name": "wetube",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Leonard Choo",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.21.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node init.js --delay 2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Searched

Perhaps [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723769/7414387) is related?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) says: "_Certain bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment._"

Comment: Are the init.js and app.js in the same folder? and also which tutorial are you following?

Comment: @Supercool. You can see that they are in the same folder from the screenshot. It's a paid course so I can't share it :(

Answer (score 0):

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register

`babel-node` uses `@babel/register` internally. And `@babel/register` does not support compiling native Node.js ES modules on the fly, since currently there is no stable API for intercepting ES modules loading.

So, currently there is no way to use both of them, `@babel/register` and `ES modules`.(`type: module` will make your nodejs treats every js file as `ES module`)

Comment: No way to use both of them - are you sure?

Comment: @Nelles  if we use the word 'use' for a official support, yes, there is no way to use both of them at same time. `@babel/register` doesn't support nodejs native `ES module` system.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register#compiling-plugins-and-presets-on-the-fly

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! But I'm not sure how this is related the file extension ;(

Comment: @Leonard 
`babel` is parsing `js` files and rewrite all `unsupported` grammars to `supported` one.
you set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. 
I think the `babel` parser has a bug for loading `es module with native node`.