# import "./app.js" works but "./app" does not. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I'm making an app using Express and Node.js. I'm using Babel as well.

For this line in `init.js`

```
import app from "./app.js";
```

"./app.js" works ✅

"./app" doesn't work

**Why does this happen?**

A paid course I'm following has "./app" working, and other people seem to have no problem with it.

Comment: Show your babel (and any other relevant) config files

Comment: the resolution of an extension in most javascript apps is done through webpack.

see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions

For babel there is a plugin with enables this, which may be relevant in a node js application:
https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/master/DOCS.md

Comment: @Phix Here is the link containing my files related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754828/import-app-from-app-does-not-work-but-its-supposed-to-work

Comment: @lkroneman It says on the first link "which is what enables users to leave off the extension when importing:" so it should work...