# Why is Javascript module with ".js" file extension not found on import unless file extension is .mjs despite package "type" being "module"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following quote from the ECMAScript documentation and minimal reproducible code example,
why does using the `.js` file extension for an Javascript ES module import cause an `ERR_MDOULE_NOT_FOUND` error when `package.json` has `"type": "module"`?

From [Node.js v16.3.0 documentation - Determining module system](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system) (emphasis mine)

> Determining module system
>
> Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to node as the initial input, or when referenced by import statements within ES module code:
>
> - Files ending in .mjs.
> - ***Files ending in .js when the nearest parent package.json file contains a top-level "type" field with a value of "module".***

The documentation says that a `.js` file extension is treated as an ES module as long as we declare our package's type as `module`.

Now consider the following minimal reproducible example of how a `.js` file does not get treated as an ES Module unless renamed to `.mjs`.

---

`package.json`

```json
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

---

`foo.js`

```js
export default 'foo module';
```

---

`index.js`

```js
import foo from './foo';

console.log("Hello", foo);
```

---

With the above file names and code, the following error occurs.

```sh
$ node index.js
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/georgep/nodemodulestest/foo' imported from /Users/georgep/nodemodulestest/index.js
Did you mean to import ../foo.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:307:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:742:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853:11)
    at Loader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:89:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:242:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:73:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:72:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

But, if I change the following

1. change `foo.js` to `foo.mjs`, and
2. Update the `import` in `index.js` to reflect `foo.mjs` => `import foo from './foo.mjs';`

Then the program executes without error.

Why is the `.mjs` file ending necessary in this situation, when the documentation clearly states that setting `"type": "module"` in `package.json` should mean that node treats regular `.js` files like ES modules?

Environment:

```sh
$ node -v
v16.3.0
```

Comment: in ESM, [file extension is mandatory](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions). Use `import foo from './foo.js'`.

Comment: Thanks @ASDFGerte, right as you pointed this out I also found this fact in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63460038/2291928 . Yes, the `.js` file extension is mandatory. I misunderstood this difference between ES Modules and CommonJS. Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723678/node-experimental-modules-error-cannot-find-module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by [@ASDFGerte in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851875/why-is-javascript-module-with-js-file-extension-not-found-on-import-unless-fi/67852006#comment119930181_67851875), and also fully explained in [this answer to "Omit the file extension, ES6 module NodeJS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459159/omit-the-file-extension-es6-module-nodejs/63460038#63460038):

In ES Modules, [file extension is mandatory](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions), so you cannot omit the `.js` file extension like you can in CommonJS.

This was the source of my confusion. Once I include the file extension, ES Modules work. For example, this works.

`index.js`

```js
import foo from './foo.js';
```

The solution feels pretty obvious, but without knowing the exact reason, this difference between the CommonJS convention and ES Modules would have felt like a bug anyways, so I'm happy to have learned how each module system treats its file extensions.

Comment: You can pass experimental parameters to `node` which don't require file extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558982/327074