# Why am I unable to import an exported array in my script? Getting [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `translations.ts` file located at `project/src/services/translations.js` that exports the following array:

```
export const supportedLocales = ['en', 'es'];
```

And I am attempting to import it in `generateStrings.mjs` file which is located at `project/src/scripts/generateStrings.mjs` like this:

```
import { supportedLocales } from '../services/translations';
```

But I get an error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/mobile/src/services/translations' imported from /Users/User/Desktop/Projects/mobile/src/scripts/generateStrings.mjs
```

My IDE couldn't automatically import the array either only in that specific file. I wonder if it is because the file has `.mjs` extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Javascript module with ".js" file extension not found on import unless file extension is .mjs despite package "type" being "module"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851875/why-is-javascript-module-with-js-file-extension-not-found-on-import-unless-fi)

Comment: @lusc I imagine that is the problem, however, in my case just adding .js here import { supportedLocales } from '../services/translations.js'; didn't really do anything.

Answer (score 0):

mistype, import from `translationS`, and file named `translation.js` without `S` at the end

Comment: Sorry I mistyped that as I was writing the question, but in my code that mistake doesn't exist.