# SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'connect'

Tags: javascript, node.js

when i use require commonjs everything is working

```
const { Schema, connect } = require("mongoose");

connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/usersdb", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

but  when i use import es6 i get error

```
import { connect } from "mongoose";

connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/usersdb",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
);
```

> SyntaxError: The requested module >'file:///C:/Users/Rich%20Warrior/Desktop/mon0022/node_modules/mongoose/index>.js' does not provide 
>   an export named 'connect'

and if you write like that

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/usersdb", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

> TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dur",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -r esm src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.8",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

I want to use the es6 module.Is there a way to use es6 modules with mongoose without getting an error?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node)

Comment: Have you tried `import mongoose from "mongoose";` ? The error seems pretty clear that there is no **named** export `connect`. So `import * as mongoose from "mongoose";` won't help either since it only imports named exports.

Comment: @FelixKling why here is `import mongoose, {connect} from" mongoose ";` doesn’t work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `import mongoose, {connect} from" mongoose ";` doesn't work because you are again trying to import an export named `connect` which does not exist. As I said, try `import mongoose from "mongoose";` and then access it with `mongoose.connect`.

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS doesn't support it yet. You will have to use something like [bable](https://babeljs.io/). Check this out from [NodeJS doc](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) as well.

Comment: If that was the problem then the OP would get a different error. The error "does not provide an export named 'connect'" makes it pretty clear that ES6 module *syntax* works fine.