# How to run nodejs child_process in es6?

Tags: javascript, fork, babeljs, child-process

Following simple code:

```
const { exec, spawn, fork, execFile } = require('child_process')


const startAllJobs = async () => {
  const process = fork('app/util/nlp/sentenceHelper.js');
};
```

sentenceHelper:

```
import { split } from 'sentence-splitter';
/*....more but unimportant since it breaks at first line*/
```

Babel setup:

starter.js

```
// Transpile all code following this line with babel and use 'env' (aka ES6) preset.
require("@babel/register")({
  extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env"
  ], "@babel/preset-typescript"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
})
require("@babel/polyfill");

require('datejs');


// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require('./app/index.js');
```

Error:

```
import { split } from 'sentence-splitter';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

How can I use ES6 Syntax within child processes?

Node version: 12.0.0

Comment: This problem isn't about `child-process`, but ES6 modules. Do you really need to use ES6 modules with node.js?

Comment: You could use ES6 modules in Node 12: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: But IMO is better to use commonjs in Node, because the ecosystem in Node already use it for a long time