# How to run esnext file from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am kinda new typescript and I wrote an SDK, My .tsconfig looks kinda like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./lib",
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I build this using `tsc` command. Now I created localtest.js file where I am importing this

```
import getWorkspace from './lib/index'

const randomFunc = async () => {
   // some code 
}
randomFunc()
```

and then running it with following command in my terminal `node localtest.js` which is throwing following error

```
function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import getWorkspace from './lib/index'
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Any idea on how I can fix it and why I am getting the above error

Comment: That isn't even legal ES 6: imports and exports have to be top-level statements. You can't do it inside of a function. Why does it have to be ES 6 modules anyways?

Answer (score 3):

Node doesn't accept ES6 imports in `.js` files by default.

- On Node 12, add `--experimental-modules` flag. If it's lower -- you'd have to upgrade.
- Either change the extension to `.mjs`, or...
- to use ESModules in `.js` files (like the ones emitted by TS), add `"type": "module"` to the nearest package.json.

More info:

- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854500/6003547

---

Alternatively, you can change ["module" compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to "commonjs" to emit `require`s.

Answer (score 2):

Node is supporting this but it is still experimental. You need to set up a few things.

1. You need Node.js version 12+
2. You need a flag `--experimental-modules` and set to use it.
3. Change `type` to `module` in your `package.json`

```
node --experimental-modules localtest.js
```

```
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

You can read the documentation about this [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).