# How to use ES6(esm) imports/exports in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, es6-modules

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
import UtilModuler from '@utilModuler'

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

> import UtilModuler from '@utilModuler';
>          ^^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)

***Caveats***

I'm using third party libraries(@utilModuler) which were written via import/exports. Possible workarounds:

1. Fork library and generate cjs file with rollup.
2. [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) works like a charm but it cause unnesecary memory consumptions

**Question**: is there are a way how to use hybrid import cjs and esm in google cloud function?(except options which I described above)

Would be nice to use in deploy function something like [--experimental-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854500/6892740)

Comment: No need to fork the library to transpile it?

Comment: You may want to use webpack or Babel.  How is your project structured?

Comment: Yeah actually rollup, webpack and Bable could handle this. 
Structure:
`--package
  -- UtilModuler 
--package
  -- ...
-- src(vue.js)
-- functions(google cloud functions)`
Packages could use for frontend and backend.

Comment: what was your solution at the end of the day? Facing the same thing,

Comment: I used rollup to transpile them into cjs modules.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like, ESM support has been added by the latest version of the firebase CLI (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v9.15.0):

```
$ npm install -g firebase-tools # Get the latest firebase-cli
$ firebase deploy --only functions # Deploy as usual
```

and

1. You must select nodejs14 runtime.
2. You must manually include latest version of @google-cloud/functions-framework dependency.
   e.g.

```
// package.json
...
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.9.0",
    ...
  },
```

and an example function:

```
// index.js
import functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Comment: Note: If using GCP Cloud Functions (not through Firebase) they automatically include the latest `@google-cloud/functions-framework` as noted by one of the authors in https://medium.com/google-cloud/es-modules-in-cloud-functions-f5be1676c8b5

Comment: Can someone please help? The answer works fine, but when I use this, it says "Must use import to load ES Module: .eslintrc.js"

Comment: you don't need `"@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.9.0",` anymore as of 2023

Answer (score 1):

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/register": "^7.0.0"
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

entry point node.js app

```
require("@babel/register")({})

// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require('./index.js')
```

Comment: I had to specify the dependencies as regular dependencies (not as devDependencies)