# Google Cloud Functions: Deployment failure when attempting to use ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904599/how-to-use-es6esm-imports-exports-in-cloud-functions) is similar, but did not help.

We see this error when using ES6 on Google Cloud Functions:

> ```
> Deployment failure:
> Build failed: /workspace/index.js:4 import { get } from 'axios'; ^  SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at new Script (vm.js:83:7) at
> ```
>
> checkScriptSyntax (internal/bootstrap/node.js:620:5) at startup
> (internal/bootstrap/node.js:280:11) at bootstrapNodeJSCore
> (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3); Error ID: d984e68f

How can we use ES6 syntax with Google Cloud Function?

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Required Modules
 */
import { get } from 'axios';
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';


/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
export async function run(req, res) {
  // Set API end point.
  let apiURL = 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml';

  // Wrap API parameters in convenient object.
  let apiData = {
    PARAM_1: 'PARAM_DATA',
    PARAM_2: 'PARAM_DATA',
  };

  // Invoke API.
  get(apiURL,
    JSON.stringify(apiData)
  )
  .then((response) => {
    //res.status(200).send(response.data);

    let xmlData = response.data;

    parseString(xmlData, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
   

 res.status(500).end();
    return;
  }
  res.status(200).send(result);
});
```

}, (error) => {
res.status(500).send(response.data);
console.log(error);
});
}

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Function Nodejs runtime [supports version 10 and 12 (beta)](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime)

To use the `import { } from ""` syntax in Nodejs versions <= 12, you have to save the file as `.mjs` and run with the `--experimental-modules` flag. However, Google Cloud Functions don't allow you to pass in flags, ***so this is not an option for this use-case***.

You could use [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-core.html), either transpile and deploy, or using [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register#docsNav), or skip babel and use [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm). Another option would be to use Cloud Run, but that will require extra steps (ie: docker).

Just to add, in Nodejs versions >= 13, you only need to add `{ "type": "module" }` to the package.json (no need to use the flag).

Comment: thanks for this explanation! given this, it's unclear why the source editor prompts you to use ES6 since it's not supported natively yet.

Comment: @Crashalot  it is only to highlight the code, I know that it may be confusing.