# Gulp throws error 'Must use import to load ES Module'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

We're converting our `gulpfile.js` in node `v13.8.0` to ES6 as following:

```js
import { src, dest, series, parallel, watch } from 'gulp'
import nodemon from 'gulp-nodemon' // normal nodemon does not display an error on app crash
import env from 'gulp-env'
import browser from 'browser-sync'
import sass from 'gulp-sass'
// Tasks
export default {
    cssTranspile: cssTranspile,
    jsTranspile: jsTranspile,
    server: series(startNodemon, startBrowserSync),
    default: series(
        parallel(
            cssTranspile,
            jsTranspile
        ),
        startNodemon,
        startBrowserSync,
        function () {
            watch('public/scss/*.scss', cssTranspile)
        }
    )
}
```

The error reported, when simply running `gulp`, is:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: T:\Node\ICP\gulpfile.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

I must be doing something wrong. Anyone an idea on what it might be?

```
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

The flag `"type": "module",` is set in `package.json` as described in the [note docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field). The issue is very much similar to [this issue](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib/issues/208) in the geolib library.

And when we rename `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.babel.js` as described [here](https://firxworx.com/blog/wordpress/using-gulp4-and-rsync-to-deploy-locally-and-beyond/) we get the same error.

The `package.json` contain these packages:

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-env": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/env"
    ]
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.mjs`, then using the `--gulpfile gulpfile.mjs` flag on the command line? Maybe that will force `loader.js` to use import.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion `gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.mjs` but it returns the same error `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: T:\ICP\gulpfile.mjs`

Comment: Hmm. Maybe there's a bug in Node's loader.js. that's forcing it to use `require`. They do warn that import/export are experimental. Here's where that error is coming from: `if (filename.endsWith('.mjs') && !Module._extensions['.mjs']) { throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename); }`

Comment: If the "modules" you are importing don't use es6 import/exports you will have to do extra work to get them to work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node last answer.

Comment: Thank you @Mark, I opened an issue with [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2417) to see what can be done.

Answer (score 5):

In an answer to my own question, when the flag `"type": "module"` is set in package.json you can't use `gulp`. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2417#issuecomment-586206969).

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be fixed now: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/pull/214. Be sure to install the latest version of `gulp-cli` (2.3.0 as of June 2020).

If your package.json specifies `"type": "module"` you can name your ES module with Gulp tasks `gulpfile.js`, otherwise name it `gulpfile.mjs`. No need to use any transpilers or preloaders like esm, Babel or TypeScript.