# Can you use ES6 import/export in typicode json-server

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, json-server

I'm using https://github.com/typicode/json-server to stand up a mock API. I'm using a `.js` file to programmatically generate the data. I would like to use the `import`/`export default` syntax to import and export javascript, but I can't get it to build.

I would like to use:

```
import data from './data';

export default () => {
  return {data: data};
};
```

But the only way I can get it to work is using this syntax:

```
const data = require('./data');

module.exports = () => {
  return {data: data};
};
```

This is sitting in a file called `db.js`, and I run the mock API using `json-server --watch db.js`. The same issue applies to the `data.js` file. Here is the error I get when trying to run it:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
...
```

I have tried moving this to different subdirectories with no success. Is there anything I can do to allow this app to run with the `import`/`export default` syntax?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can/did you check if the answers in this post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: None of those answers worked for me. I believe it's because those answers use ```node``` to run the app and I am using ```json-server```.

Comment: You're writing standard node JS so you can use whatever ECMAScript syntax your particular node version (and V8 engine) supports, which might surprise you it will have most the new constructs you are used to using short of import statements.  If you must use import/export, you'd need to setup babel to transpile your modern ES to node friendly-ES to get it to work.

Comment: json-server is a node application and library

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `"type": "module"` in the package.json if your Node version is 13.0.0 or more.