# Why is import module causing "Property does not exist on type 'typeof import" when require works fine?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite

I'm running into an issue using the npm module "sqlite".

When I use ***const db = require('sqlite')*** I am able to call ***db.all(query)*** from one of my express routes successfully.

However, switching to ***import db as sqlite*** is causing the following error:

> **Property 'all' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/admin/Documents/code/node-rss/node_modules/sqlite/main")**

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

Sorry, I tried Googling around but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Does your nodejs support imports? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: Yep, I'm using them with a few other modules (express, cors, etc.). I guess I could always just use one "const db = require('sqlite')". As that works fine. It would just be nice to have the uniformity.