# How to include functions of JavaScript files in the Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a typescript file in which some functions have been added. 
The following shows the actual address of the typescript file :

> ../myproject/src/util/validation/user-validation

All the functions are exported from the file. For instance,

```
export function validateSignUpData(userDetail:UserDetail):Array<String>{

    let errorMessages = new Array<String>();
    /* Some Code */
```

Now I am trying to use the exported function in Node server, though it throws an error which I do not comprehend.

> Error: Cannot find module '../myproject/src/util/validation/user-validation'

This is how I tried to get the functions inside my Node server file:

```
app.post('/users',(req,res)=>{

    let validator = require('../myproject/src/util/validation/user-validation');
    let errorMessages = validator.validateSignUpData(req.body);
```

I googled **require** function, and it seemed that my code must work properly. Some forums suggests that typescript must be installed to resolve the issue, though I have already installed typescript!

I will be glad, if you help me! 
Thank you.

Comment: You've to compile Your code using tsc and then run result of it

Comment: Are you sure `../myproject/src/util/validation/user-validation` is correct path? Seems like you messed up with folder structure

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Yes, I am sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `export` keyword is used for [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) ([Related article also covering node.js](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/)). This is a new language feature that was shipped in 2015.

It uses `export function name() {...}` to export a function and `import {name} from './path/to/file';` to import it somewhere else.

Node uses the [CommonJs](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp) syntax (which is still largely popular).

The idea behind it is that any module (i.e. js-file) can export an object like this: `module.exports = {key: "value"}`. This object can then be imported using `require('./path/to/file')`.

You can use es6 modules in node like this: [How can I use an es6 import in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node/45854500#45854500).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods of modules in node js, es6 modules and requrejs

require is used together with module.exports
add this to your module
module.exports.validateSignUpData=validateSignUpData
and then the require function will export it.

The other way is to use es6 modules but it doesn't work under all circumstances 
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Comment: Uhhh, ES6 modules are supported in node.  Not sure that has anything to do with the  OP's question, but thought I should correct that statement in your answer.