# (0 , _axios.default) is not a function when mocking axios with interceptors

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, axios

My app has a file which creates an instance of axios with interceptors and then the api's use this instance to make calls. The issue is when i try to write test for this api it fails with `TypeError: (0 , _axios.default) is not a function` error.

below is the poc which creates the axios instance:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  timeout: 20000,
  paramsSerializer(params) {
    return qs.stringify(params, { indices: false });
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    logger.info(`Request sent to ${config.url}`, config.params);
  }

  return config;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    logger.info(`Response from ${response.config.url}`, response.data);
  }

  return parseBody(response);
}, (error) => parseError(error));

export default axiosInstance;
```

this is the api that uses the axios instance

```
const triviaAPI = {
  getQuestions: async (amount) => axiosInstance({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://opentdb.com/api.php',
    params: {
      amount,
    },
  }).then((response) => response.results)
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    }),
};

export default triviaAPI;
```

and this is the axios mock

```
import mockAxios from 'jest-mock-axios';

export default {
  ...mockAxios,
  ...{
    create: jest.fn(() => ({
      ...mockAxios,
      defaults: {
        headers: {
          common: {},
        },
      },
      interceptors: {
        request: {
          use: jest.fn(),
        },
        response: {
          use: jest.fn(),
        },
      },
      get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { total_payout: 100.21 } })),
    })),
  },
};
```

and finally this is the test case

```
describe('triviaAPI', () => {
  it('should return a successful response', async () => {
    const data = await triviaAPI.getQuestions(10);
    console.log(data);
    expect(Array.isArray(data)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

when i run the test i get the below error
[image]

I have searched around a lot but found no solution yet. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it may not be working is because you are using `export` which isnt yet supported in nodejs by default you can however enable it using an experimental node.js feature as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641589/12887221) however thats not recommended therefore i would recommend using [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm)

So for your use case:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "axios-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node -r esm ." //Important
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "esm": "^3.2.25" //Important
  }
}
```

**axiosInstance.js**:

```
import axios from "axios" //Important

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    timeout: 20000,
    paramsSerializer(params) {
        return JSON.stringify(params, { indices: false });
    },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        logger.info(`Request sent to ${config.url}`, config.params);
    }

    return config;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        logger.info(`Response from ${response.config.url}`, response.data);
    }

    return response;
}, (error) => Promise.reject(error));

export default axiosInstance; //Important
```

**main.js**:

```
import axiosInstance from "./axiosInstance.js" //Important

const triviaAPI = {
    getQuestions: async (amount) => axiosInstance({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://opentdb.com/api.php',
        params: {
            amount,
        },
    }).then((response) => response.results)
        .catch((error) => {
            throw error;
        }),
};

async function main() {
    const data = await triviaAPI.getQuestions(10);
    console.log(data);
}

main()
```

***NOTICE***: Some code was changed in my axiosInstance.mjs as the question didn't include what they were so I have marked all relevant changes with `//Important`

**Also**: If you want to see an example using the experimental features please check the edit history of this answer.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but the problem is the test case not working, the axis instance works fine with all calls. I need to fix the mocking part

Comment: im not 100% sure what you mean as the line that is causing an error in the screenshot now works with the changes i made

Comment: currently the output of `response.results` is undefined as the API doesnt return any data however if i do `response` i get a console log with all the info about the request.
Console logs: https://pastebin.com/r17iRfQX

Comment: i am sorry for not being clear but the issue i am facing is that the error occurs when i run the test case
```
describe('triviaAPI', () => {
  it('should return a successful response', async () => {
    const data = await triviaAPI.getQuestions(10);
    console.log(data);
    expect(Array.isArray(data)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```
the test case has been mentioned in the question as well