# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when running ts-node in Angular Package Format project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ts-node, angular-package-format

I'm trying to run a typescript file with `ts-node`.  Getting a weird error:

```
 import { tes } from "./tes";
       ^
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)

If I copy the project `ts` files into an empty directory and try to run the file without any configuration it works fine, so it's something in the configuration.

I also tried generating a brand new angular package format project:

```
ng new proj --create-application=false
cd proj
ng g library x
```

And if I delete all the `tsconfig` files associated with the project and the library, `ts-node` runs fine.  When I leave them in I get the same error.

The `tes` file is inside a Angular Package Format library.  This is the top level `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "csv": [
        "dist/csv/csv",
        "dist/csv"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

This is the project specific `tsconfig.lib.json` :

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your tsconfig is set to output js using `esnext` modules, which aren't understood by node without configuration. You can either:

1. Remove the `"module": "esnext",` line from your `tsconfig.json`
2. Or, assuming you want to keep your config for Angular, configure your node to use the new ES module syntax e.g. by following [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node#45854500)