# Error on Importing Module using import { } from ' '

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to import a module in Node.js, but I keep getting this error:

```
import { test } from "Modulename";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Before Node v13 this syntax wasn't supported without an experimental flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: Could you give some more details - what version of Node, what (if any) transpilation, ...?

Comment: I am using v10.20.1 of node