# import React from 'react' SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

My problem is that when I run "node index.js" I get this message:

```
Users/martina/JPMC-tech-task-2-PY3/index.js:1
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:994:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:813:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1046:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

this seems to say that there is a problem with the import on the first line of my index.js file, but i have no idea how to solve this problem. thank u if anyone can help!

my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "jpmc-tech-task-2-py3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "s",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "repository": {

    "url": "git+https://github.com/insidesherpa/JPMC-tech-task-2-PY3.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/insidesherpa/JPMC-tech-task-2-PY3/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/insidesherpa/JPMC-tech-task-2-PY3#readme",
  "type": "module"
}
```

basically what i'm being asked to do is that while having an http server on another terminal window i'm supposed to do "npm start" on this terminal and it should open a localhost web page with some data. (it's an assignment but i don't understand much of it) however npm start is not in my package.json by default and i saw that it seems to just be supposed to throw index.js, so that's what i'm trying to do but failing

Comment: Hey Martina, welcome to SO.  Unfortunately, there is not enough information or code to properly assist you.  For better results, try giving us a little information about how you got to this point and attach the pertinent code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't support es6 import syntax, or didn't until recently.

I'm not exactly sure what your needs are, but here's some options:

- Use a new version of node and .mjs. [Check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node).
- use `require` instead.
- I've also had some success with the [esm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm run start:dev`

items in the `script` array of package.json are run by using the command `npm run` before the name of the script.