# Run Javascript with Node imports from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am kind of unfamiliar with running javascript from command line, but I am in a situation where need to use a NPM package for a Panasonic AC, that has a wrapper for their unofficial API.

However, I want to make a simple JS that I can run from command line, that will import the NPM package. But this only generates error:

```
(node:68628) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/Ronny/Documents/AC/index.js:1
import { ComfortCloudClient } from 'panasonic-comfort-cloud-client'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Is it not possible to do this?

Comment: Depends on your node version and the package itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Answer (score 1):

Its possible using node `require()` function

```js
const { ComfortCloudClient } = require('panasonic-comfort-cloud-client')
```

Comment: This fixed the error message, but now it says "ReferenceError: client is not defined". So it seems like there's more to it.