# Importing RRule from rrule package in TypeScript. Getting SyntaxError: The requested module 'rrule' is expected to be of type CommonJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, rrule

**Update**: Tried to create a minimal repro here: https://github.com/aioobe/node-issue-repro. It's very stripped down obviously, but it exhibits the same error message.

```
git clone git@github.com:aioobe/node-issue-repro.git
cd node-issue-repro
npm install
npx tsc && node build/index.js
```

---

In my TypeScript source code I have the following:

```
import { RRule } from 'rrule';

// ...

const oddDays = new RRule({
    freq: RRule.DAILY,
    bymonthday: [1, 3, 5]
});
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
(node:31434) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution in ESM is experimental.
file:///home/aioobe/projects/test/server/database/storage.ts:10
import { RRule } from 'rrule';
         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'rrule' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from 'rrule';
const { RRule } = pkg;
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:98:21)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:137:5)
    at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:165:24)
    at Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! daily-challenge@0.1.0 start-server: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --loader ts-node/esm --es-module-specifier-resolution=node server/server.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the daily-challenge@0.1.0 start-server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aioobe/.npm/_logs/2020-09-13T15_53_32_162Z-debug.log
npm run start-server exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
```

In my `package.json` I have

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "rrule": "^2.6.6",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "type": "module"
}
```

(I need `"type": "module"`, otherwise I'm running into `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.)

In my `tsconfig.json` I have

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I've noted that in [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) the [`package.json`](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule/blob/master/package.json) does *not* have `"type": "module"`, which according to [this page](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field) means that it should be interpreted as CommonJS.

Honestly, I don't really know what this means for me. I've tried all kinds of syntax variations to include this package in my file (including the one suggested in the error message). I run into various errors, but the syntax posted above is the exact syntax used in the [example code](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) in the readme.

I use node version 14.9.0, npm version 6.14.8, typescript version 3.7.2 and ts-node 8.10.2. I'm happy to upgrade/downgrade, but I'm running into the same issue with node 12 unfortunately.

I use lots of other modules the above way without any problem.

Comment: Could you please provide minimal environment with issue reproduced, I tried on simple typescript demo environment but couldn't reproduce it on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pwn3lo

Comment: Minimal repro uploaded to gitub repo. `git clone git@github.com:aioobe/node-issue-repro.git`, `cd node-issue-repro`, `npm install`, `npx tsc && node build/index.js`.

Comment: updating import statement to `import RRule from 'rrule';` or `import { default as RRule } from 'rrule';` seems to be working.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue on node: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32137. Let me know if the fix works for you and I can add it as an answer.

Comment: @DipenShah, error goes away, but it doesn't seem to work. I get `undefined` for `RRule.DAILY` for example, and `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: RRule is not a constructor`

Comment: It's strange, I can see value for RRule but RRule.DAILY is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "rrule" module seems to declare an invalid `index.d.ts`.

It says `export default RRule;` but the default export is the entire module.

This is simple enough to work around:

```
import pkg from "rrule";
const { RRule } = pkg as any;
```

This behaves equivalently to:

```
import * as pkg from "rrule";
const { RRule } = pkg.default as any;
```

We need to use `any` here due to the fact TS thinks this is `typeof RRule`, even though if you print it you will see it's actually the whole module body. This is possibly an upstream bug, or a bug with the experimental ESM support.

Comment: I'm really glad you put the "This behaves equivalently to:" piece of code. In my project running locally the regular import works, but when I build a Docker container, it only works when using import * as etc. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using **commonjs** as module code generation type fixes the issue.
Following changes are required:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "module": "commonjs",
    ...
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "type": "commonjs",
  ...
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import { RRule } from "rrule";
```

Comment: When I make this change, I run into `(node:5064) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
/home/aioobe/projects/dc/server/server.ts:1
import express from 'express';` I will try to update the minimal repro to reflect this too.

Comment: If I google this error, all I come up with is answers like these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854500/276052 that basically say "you must user `"type": "module"`.

Comment: Also, `"module": "commonjs"` immediately gets reverted to `"module": "esnext"` when I launch my application. In the logs it says `The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.module must be esnext (for import() and import/export)`

Comment: Seems like you project has some config which is forcing esnext module generator. May be you are using nextjs https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7361

Comment: @aioobe any luck so far?

Comment: I don't use nextjs to the extent of my knowledge. I still have not managed to strip down my main project to reproduce the issue described in my last comment. :-/ Still trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the import statement:

```
import { RRule } from 'rrule';
```

with:

```
import pkg from 'rrule';
const {RRule} = (pkg as any);
```

This worked on Node.js v14.11.0.

It is actually suggested in the error message that you've received:

```
(node:31434) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution in ESM is experimental.
file:///home/aioobe/projects/test/server/database/storage.ts:10
import { RRule } from 'rrule';
         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'rrule' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from 'rrule';
const { RRule } = pkg;
```

Comment: I've tried that. (Actually mentioned that in my post.) I can try again and let you know what error I got...