# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' while exporting function Js

Tags: javascript, function, export

I'm trying to export a function from a Js file but recieving a `Unexpected token` error

```
const youtubeDownload = require("./youtube/youtube-download"); // export function youtubeDownload 
const twitterDonwload = require("./twitter/twitter-download"); // export function twitterDownload

function download(tweet) {
    if(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str == null) return youtubeDownload(tweet);
    if(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str != null) return twitterDonwload(tweet);
};

export { download };
```

This code is returning the error:

```
export { download };
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Comment: Your code has to be in a *module*, as recognized by whatever environment is involved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you are using CommonJS modules by default in NodeJS. CommonJS modules doesn't support `export` syntax. So you may need to use CommonJS export syntax for this.

```js
const youtubeDownload = require("./youtube/youtube-download"); // export function youtubeDownload 
const twitterDonwload = require("./twitter/twitter-download"); // export function twitterDownload

function download(tweet) {
    if(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str == null) return youtubeDownload(tweet);
    if(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str != null) return twitterDonwload(tweet);
};

module.exports = { download };
```

Or if you really wants to use `export` syntax, you can use ES6 modules as here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854500/13568664.

Answer (score 8):

use `module.exports={download}` to export

use `const {download}=require('<yourfilepath>')` to import