# How to convert postcss.config.js and tailwind.config.js to ES modules?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, tailwind-css

I created a new Vue app using Vite via `npm init vue@latest`. I added TailwindCSS to the project based on [the official guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite).

Running `npm run lint` throws errors

> error  'module' is not defined  no-undef

because it wants *postcss.config.js* and *tailwind.config.js* to be ES modules (I think).

When converting *postcss.config.js* from

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

to

```
export const plugins = {
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
};
```

and *tailwind.config.js* from

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

to

```
export const content = ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"];
export const theme = {
  extend: {},
};
export const plugins = [];
```

and running `npm run dev` the app crashes with the error

> [vite] Internal server error: Unexpected token 'export'
> Plugin: vite:css

How do I solve this linting error?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Do the tools you're using support ESM in their configs? I would suggest not linting config files with the same rules as your code.

Comment: Why? What value would it add? Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js?

Comment: ok other question: How would you fix this linting error? Ignore those files when linting?

Comment: Exactly, why are you linting the config files at all? Remember, these files are to configure tools. There could be some value, but I would think for now you should ignore them

Answer (score 30):

You can actually keep those config files as CommonJS. ESLint's [`env`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments) needs to be set to `node` in those config files because Node is the actual environment during the build.

### Option 1: Use inline comment to configure ESLint

Insert this comment at the top of `postcss.config.js` and `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
```

### Option 2: Configure `env` for `*.config.js`

Configure [`overrides`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#how-do-overrides-work) to set `env` for `*.config.js` files:

```js
// .eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  ⋮
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.config.js'],
      env: {
        node: true,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

If using VS Code, you'll likely need to restart the ESLint server (or the IDE) to reload the configuration.

### Option 3: Disable ESLint rules for `*.config.js`

Configure [`ignorePatterns`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code#ignorepatterns-in-config-files) to not lint these config files:

```js
// .eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  ⋮
  ignorePatterns: ['*.config.js'],
}
```

If using VS Code, you'll likely need to restart the ESLint server (or the IDE) to reload the configuration.

Comment: I have tried all these solutions with no luck. It builds on my dev server but I get the error when I rub build on production.

Answer (score 8):

Rename the files to `postcss.config.cjs` resp. `tailwind.config.cjs`. Note the `c` in `cjs`, which stands fro CommonJS Module.