# Prettier fails when declaring { "type": "module" } in package.json

Tags: es6-modules, prettier

I have defined a prettier config in `prettier.config.js`.

After adding `"type": "module"` to package.json (to [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854500/2054731) using import/export syntax in node), running prettier fails with the following error:

```sh
Checking formatting...
[error] Invalid configuration file `prettier.config.js`: Must use import to load ES Module: /your/project/path/prettier.config.js
[error] require() of ES modules is not supported.
[error] require() of /your/project/path/prettier.config.js from /your/project/path/node_modules/prettier/third-party.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
[error] Instead rename prettier.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /your/project/path/package.json.
[error] 
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I'm using SublimeText 3 with [JSPrettier](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsPrettier), and it stops working too since prettier doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

This happens because adding `"type": "module"` in package.json makes all `.js` files ES modules, and then they can only be imported in other ES modules.

Prettier is not able to import `prettier.config.js` because it is now an ES module.

To fix this, avoid having a `.js` file that prettier tries to import from. Instead, you can define the prettier config in a non-`.js` file. From the prettier [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) there are several options, such as using a `.prettierrc.json` file or just putting the prettier config into `package.json`.

Comment: "Prettier is not able to import prettier.config.js because it is now an ES module." - The docs show that ESM is an allowable format. Is what you say still the case? I ended up here because I couldn't get it to work either. Was this someting that wasn't supported but now is supported?

Comment: I haven't tried, @Relequestual. If you can get it to work you can post it as a new answer, as it might be a better solution.

Comment: Alas, my point is, it still doesn't seem to work, but as I understand, the docs say it SHOULD work. I'm trying to confirm if I'm understanding the docs correctly.

Comment: This feels like a new question, not a comment to this answer. If that's the case please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include more info about what you've done and what error you get.

Comment: Or update your prettier config to be a valid ESM file, as Prettier can now handle ESM config files.

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can use the `cjs` file extension to indicate it's a CommonJS module.

This will allow you to continue using the `require()` of plugins (not available in `*.json` configuration files.).

The file name could be `.prettierrc.cjs` as stated in [prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#:%7E:text=prettierrc.js%2C-,.prettierrc.cjs,-%2C%20prettier.config).