# Global object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have in my website a class named **classPerson** which is in dir /foo. I need to use it in dir ./bar, but since /bar is not allowed to import from /foo i do the following:

```
/foo:

  const classPerson = new classPerson();

  Object.assign(window, { classPerson });

/bar:

const person = window.classPerson.
```

I need to achieve a similar thing in node.js. How can i do it (having no **window**)

Comment: There is [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis).

Comment: since 2019 you can use `globalThis` (which you can also do instead of `window`) - browser: `globalThis === window` .... node: `globalThis === global`

Comment: Why is `bar` not allowed to import from `foo`?  That's your main problem here.  You shouldn't be looking to use globals in nodejs.  Instead, you should learn how to use modularity and import/export properly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project setup, you can use either the built-in `require()` method or the es6 `import` module syntax.

in `/foo.js`

```js
export class ClassPerson { ... } // add the export keyword to the class definition

export const classPersonInstance = new classPerson(); // add the export keyword to the class instance if you want to use the same instance
```

in `/bar.js`

```
const foo = require('./foo.js');
const instance = foo.classPersonInstance;

// or
import { classPersonInstance } from './foo.js';
```

**NOTE**
To be able to use the import syntax, you should do some [additional configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js)

Here is the nodejs documentation for [ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering! please read my question again, i cant import. I want to achieve it similar to the code i posted, doing the same idea, not to import

Comment: @YTG No probs! if this answer wokred for you, please take the time to accept this answer by ticking the check icon on the left.