# TypeScript monorepo `import type` parse error

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, next.js, tsconfig

**_________ SETUP _________**

I have a **pnpm workspace** with the following structure:

```
workspace/
├── apps/
├───── nextjs-app/
├──────── package.json 
├──────── tsconfig.json  
├──────── ...
├── packages/
├───── api/
├──────── package.json 
├──────── tsconfig.json 
├──────── index.ts
├── tsconfig.base.json
└── package.json
```

The `nextjs-app` is a Next.js starter with all the TS preconfigured, except I modified all the `tsconfig.json` files. Here are the three TS config files' contents:

**./tscofnig.base.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

**./apps/nextjs-app/tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**./packages/api/tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": ["index.ts"]
}
```

In addition, `./packages/api/package.json` contains the following two settings:

```json
{
  ...
  "name": "@my-app/api",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "types": "./index.ts"
  ...
}
```

Finally, in order to install the workspace package in my NextJS project, I run the following command:

`pnpm --filter nextjs-app add @my-app/api@workspace:*`

**_________ PROBLEM _________**

If I have `export const foo = 'bar';` in the API package, I can easily import it anywhere in my Next.js application using `import { foo } from '@my-app/api';`. This all works perfectly fine.

But if I try to use `import type` or `export type` syntax in the API package, I get the following error:

```
../../packages/api/index.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export const foo = 'bar';
| 
> export type Foo = 'bar';
|
```

This never happens otherwise, i.e. I'm able to `import type` and `export type` as long as it all happens within the NextJS project. But as soon as I do it in the API package, I get the error.

Comment: Check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use an ES6 import in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar. For your given config, I would guess that

```
"noEmit": true
```

in your base tsconfig is going to prevent output. You might try defining a couple more fields

```
outDir: "./dist", // as an example
noEmit: false,
declaration: true
```

in `/api/tsconfig.json`. Once you re-run the `tsc` compiler, the `outDir` should have the types you're looking for. If not, hopefully you can have some hints as to what might be amiss.